# How to get src of from image

Tags: image, src

I have a text box with its value as <img src="http://localhost/wp/review/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Sunset.jpg" />

I have to replace this text box value to 'http://localhost/wp/review/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Sunset.jpg' That is the main target is to remove img tag and keep only the src value.

Thanks
Ashok Negi

Comment: are you scraping from some other page or is your own code generating the img tag?

Comment: Which language are you using JavaScript, PHP,..?

Answer (score 0):

Strip 10 characters from the beginning and 4 characters from the end. Or use a HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look into creating a regex to do this. Simplest method.

Answer (score 0):

hi you can use this method instead

```
$str = '<img border="0" src=\'/images/image.jpg\' alt="Image" width="100" height="100"/>';

preg_match('/(src=["\'](.*?)["\'])/', $str, $match);  //find src="X" or src='X'
$split = preg_split('/["\']/', $match[0]); // split by quotes

$src = $split[1]; // X between quotes

echo $src;
```